# include sqlite3 lib in c makfile

Tags: c, makefile, sqlite

my makefile can't find my sqlite3 library, I want to link it with a -lsqlite3 flag in the gcc commandline. Can someone tell me want I am doing wrong here.
The error message is the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
```

tom

Answer (score 1):

These days you can just download the [amalgamation](http://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html) and build it in with your project.  No more worrying about library locations and architecture matching!

For more details with your exact problem, you'll need to show us the full command line you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass `-L` followed by the directory containing the SQLite library. You can also use `pkg-config sqlite3 --libs` to get the appropriate linker flags.